# MQTT to InfluxDB giving me nothing but 0 values

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, mqtt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, influxdb

currently working on a python code that subscribes to a MQTT topic published by a RaspberryPi hooked up to a BME280 sensor reading for Temperature and Humidity then saves it to a database. I've created the database and my mqtt works after the topic with "MyMQTT" app

Problems start when i try to run it and all i get is 0s in when I try to read the database.

Any ideas?

Publisher code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import smbus2
import bme280
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

mqtt_broker = "test.mosquitto.org"
topic1 = "tp/eng/iotp_project/temp"
topic2 = "tp/eng/iotp_project/hum"

port = 1
address = 0x76
bus = smbus2.SMBus(port)

calibration_params = bme280.load_calibration_params(bus, address)

# Set the GPIO pin numbers for the fan and buzzer
fan = 23
buzzer = 22

# Set the temperature threshold for turning on the fan
fan_threshold = 24

# Set the humidity threshold for turning on the buzzer
buzzer_threshold = 80



# Initialize the GPIO pins
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(fan, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(buzzer, GPIO.OUT)

# Initialize the BME280 sensor
sensor = bme280.sample(bus, address, calibration_params)

temp = round(sensor.temperature, 2)
hum = round(sensor.humidity, 2)

def MQTT():
    my_mqtt = mqtt.Client()
    print("\nCreated client object at "+ time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    my_mqtt.connect(mqtt_broker, port=1883)
    print("--connected to broker")
    try:
        my_mqtt.publish(topic1, temp)
        print("--Temperature: %.2f C" % sensor.temperature)
        my_mqtt.publish(topic2, hum)
        print("--Humidity: %.2f %%" % sensor.humidity)
    except:
        print("--publishing error!")
    else:
        my_mqtt.disconnect()
        print("--disconnected from broker")

while True:
    MQTT()

#clean up the GPIO pins
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
```

Subscriber/InfluxDB code:

```
import argparse
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
from influxdb.client import InfluxDBClientError
import datetime
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

PASSWORD = 'root'
USER = 'root'
DBNAME = 'temperature'
HOST = 'localhost'
mqtt_broker ="test.mosquitto.org"
topic ="tp/iotp_project/temperature"
PORT = 8086
dbclient = None;
temp = 0.0;

def onMessage(client, userdata , message):
    global temp
    time.sleep(2)
    temp = float(message.payload.decode())
    print(temp)

def startMQTT():
    my_mqtt= mqtt.Client()
    my_mqtt.on_message =onMessage
    my_mqtt.connect(mqtt_broker, port = 1883)
    my_mqtt.subscribe(topic)
    my_mqtt.loop_start()

def getSensorData():
    now = time.gmtime()
    pointValues= [
        {
            "time": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", now),
            "measurement": 'reading',
            "tags": {
                "nodeId": "node_1",
            },
            "fields": {
                "Temperature": temp
            },
        }
    ]

    return(pointValues)

def main():
    startMQTT()
    dbclient = InfluxDBClient(HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD, DBNAME)

while True:
    data_point = getSensorData()
    dbclient.write_points(data_point)
    time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Current output:
[image: Current outputs]

I tried making an if else condition in the def main(): of my subscriber but the result remained the same.
was suggested by my classmates to remove any time.sleep() from my publisher codes but that still didn't work. database entries are still at 0 value

Attempted if/else def main():

```
def main():
        startMQTT()
        dbclient = InfluxDBClient(HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD, DBNAME)
        messageReceived = False
        while True:
            if messageReceived:
                data_point1 = getTemperatureData()
                data_point2 = getHumidityData()
                dbclient.write_points(data_point1)
                dbclient.write_points(data_point2)
                time.sleep(5)
            else:
                time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please edit the code to remove the extra blank lines and to ensure the indentation is correct

Comment: It makes it harder for us to read having extra blank lines between every statement, the harder you make it for us to help you less we will. Also the indentation is still wrong making it invalid Python, again making it harder to help you. Your first 2 code blocks are unreadable

Comment: Sorry to be clear, I am specifically talking about the code blocks, not the description.

Comment: Make sure you extract and provide a [mcve], please. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should put the sleep back into the publisher (and you should not be creating a new client for each loop).

Your subscriber is failing because you are missing a `global temp` from the `getSensorData()` function.

Also remove the `time.sleep(2)` from `onMessage()`